# Beginner-friendly tool to simulate HTTP flood on my website

Tags: web-application, attacks, http, ddos

Is there any easy-to-use tool available I can use to produce an HTTP GET flood on a website I maintain? If so, can you also explain in steps how to use it?

I need to do this for testing purposes. Our website is frequently the target of layer 7 HTTP floods. Seemingly a distributed bot-network is hitting the home page and taking it down in the process.

My webserver is nginx; we recently added some hardening measures to mitigate DDOS. However, it's still wasn't enough. Now I want to be able to test the efficacy of various settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were running apache then you'd already have 'ab' available. I was under the impression that 'wrk' was often distributed with nginx - it is available seperately. Alternatively httperf will do the job.

Comment: Ended up going with `ab`. Thanks symcbean. Simple way to test is a command such as `ab -n 100 -c 100 -l http://example.com`

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of DDoS Attack Tools. If you want to launch HTTP GET Floods, I'd suggest you to use [Bonesi](https://github.com/Markus-Go/bonesi), [DosHTTP](http://qpdownload.com/doshttp/), LOIC, HOIC.
However, you should notice that Bonesi is only used in LAN and you can simulate the HTTP GET Flood attacks with a predefined botnet size. On the other hand, the three tools later allow you to launch HTTP GET Flood attacks to real web servers.